# WP8 UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I have some SQL code with local database in my App, it works:

```
using(var ctx = new TestCTX()){
     var res = ctx.Test.ToList();
}
```

Then I want to use it in PeriodicTask in OnInvoke method, I get 
`UnauthorizedAccessException`:

```
public override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask){
    using(var ctx = new TestCTX()){
        var res = ctx.Test.ToList();
    }
}
```

But then I wrap it to:

```
public override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task){
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>{     
         using(var ctx = new TestCTX()){
             var res = ctx.Test.ToList();
         }
    });   
}
```

Then it works.
So here is the question: Why must I wrap it into BeginInvoke ?

Comment: Because the OnInvoke method is on your PeriodicTask's thread, but there are some control in your method must be executed on UI thread. so  you must Executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with.

Comment: What controls? I am only using Linq 2 Sql.

Comment: do you bind any data in your onInvoke method  to control?

Comment: What is the specific line that throws the exception?

Comment: edited question. thats the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, only the thread that created a **DispatcherObject** may access that object. For example, a background thread that is spun off from the main UI thread cannot update the contents of a **Button** that was created on the UI thread. In order for the background thread to access the Content property of the Button, the background thread must delegate the work to the Dispatcher associated with the UI thread. This is accomplished by using either **Invoke or BeginInvoke**. 
Invoke is synchronous and BeginInvoke is asynchronous. The operation is added to the event queue of the Dispatcher at the specified DispatcherPriority.

**BeginInvoke** is **asynchronous**;therefore, control returns immediately
    to the calling object after it is called.

**Invoke** is a **synchronous** operation; therefore, control will not return to the calling object until after the callback returns.

You can read more from the below MSDN reference. 
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reference

Comment: Thats straight simple. But i am doing nothing but sql query, no bindings, no controls. it is periodic task - no UI,

Comment: Okk So for further inspection we need more detail on TestCTX object. If possible Please add complete TestCTX class.